# Is there anything similar to return statement of C in Lisp?

Tags: lisp

I want to implement a base condition in a recursive function written in Lisp, but I'm not able to do this since there is no return statement in Lisp.

My Lisp code is based on this C code

```
if (n==0) return;
```

How do I implement this in Lisp?

Comment: Lisp is frequently used as a functional programming language.  This means outputs to term/stdout are considered to be "side-effects" and somewhat (without so heavy a negative connotation) _unclean_.  Of course, any function in Common Lisp will evaluate down to that value of its finalmost form.

Comment: So for something like _abort all this if n is equal to 0_ in a function we'll call **#'foo** you'd probably use a conditional - in most cases this would probably be the **#'cond** function but here is a simple implementation using **#'when**, an often-built-in macro. `(when (= n 0) (return-from foo nil))` In the above _when_ form, the _nil_ can be replaced by a more complicated form, but if that's necessary, you'll probably be wanting to construct an implementation of `(cond)` or `(case)` etcetera.

Comment: @miercoledi lisp is no more functional than perl, with the exception of simpler quoting. some problems cannot be solved in a functional style  without bringing in a state machine that effectively does the same thing as imperative code except the transformations in the environment are done by copy at each operation. one of these problems is partial reduction, where you want to reduce a list of steps while transforming the environment but stop reducing when a certain condition is met; "imperative" code effectively abstracts the complexity of this, while "pure functional" makes it impractical.

Comment: for example, pure functional approach struggles with expressing `find the index of the string "hi" in my array xs`, because reduce must go through the whole array even after it finds it, and filter will go through the whole array and won't even know what first is because it's intended to be an unordered operation. So there is no way to express this problem correctly without bringing in a state machine/stream/"monad", and such approach is  isomorphic to imperative approach.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Common Lisp has the special form [RETURN-FROM](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_ret_fr.htm) (and its relative [RETURN](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_return.htm)) to do what you want.

```
(defun accumulate-list (list)
  (when (null list)
    (return-from accumulate-list 0))
  (+ (first list)
     (accumulate-list (rest list))))
```

Having said that, I prefer to use [COND](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_cond.htm) when writing recursive functions.

```
(defun accumulate-list (list)
   (cond
     ((null list)
      0)
     (t
      (+ (first list)
         (accumulate-list (rest list))))))
```

Comment: Note that if a clause in a `cond` has no body forms, then if the test form returns non-nil, the result of the test form is returned. That means that you can write `(cond ((null list) 0) ((+ (first list) ...)))`;  there's no need for the `t` in this case.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor (My comment doesn't apply to CL.) In Scheme, it's still better to use `else` instead of using the expression as the test form, because the `else` expression is in tail position, whereas the test form still has to be tested for truthiness.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Good point about Scheme/CL differences;  the question is just tagged [tag:lisp], so it's not clear what the target Lisp is, but this answer uses `defun`, so I'd assumed Common Lisp.  I can see why a stand-alone test would be in non-tail position if there are following clauses, but if it's the last clause, wouldn't a stand-alone test be in tail position.  E.g., in `(cond ... ((+ 2 3)))` if you get all the way to `(+ 2 3)`, then that's going to be the return value.  It's just like the `(and ... last)` and `(or ... last)` case, isn't it?

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young (I realize, though, that Scheme has a specific list of things that are tail positions, so this might not be covered there.)

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor In Scheme, there's a difference between `#f` (which is the only false value, in Standard terms), and an "unspecified value" (which is what is returned if `cond` "falls off" the last clause, and is usually `(void)` in implementations that provide it). So a test-only last clause can't simply be optimised to be an `else`, in Scheme. (But I can see how you can do that in CL, since `nil` is both a false value and is the result of `cond` if execution falls off).

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young I'm looking at R5RS, [4.2.1 Conditionals](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/) and see that each clause is `(<test> <expression> ...)`, so (as you've reminded me in the past ;)), there can be *zero* expressions.  After that, it says, **"If the selected clause contains only the test and no expressions, then the value of the test is returned as the result."**  So Scheme *does* support `(cond ... (test))` evaluating to whatever `test` evaluates to.  (The question of whether it's a tail position or not is still open.)

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor That clause only applies if the "value of the test" is truthy. Otherwise, it falls through.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young That's the case in CL as well, so the only time there'd be an observable difference is when the last test returns `#f`, since everything else is a true value.  It's certainly an important case, though, if the last clause's test could return `#f`.  In a case like `(+ 2 3)`, though, it can't.  Good catch.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Right, I was just trying to explain why (in Scheme) you can't simply optimise a "last" test-only clause to an `else`, and thus why such test-only clauses can't be in tail position. :-)

Answer (score 4):

For a Algol programmer (or one of it's many dialects like C, Java, perl, ...) **every** expression in an LISP works like  a "return expression". Example:

```c
{
  int x = 10;
  if( x == 10 )
    return 10 * 5;
  else
    return 5 * 19; 
}
```

In LISP this can be written like these:

```lisp
;; direct version
(let ((x 10))
  (if (= x 10)
      (* 10 x)
      (* 5 x)))


;; if can be anywhere
(let ((x 10))
  (* x
     (if (= x 10) 
         10 
         5))))
```

As you might notice LISP `if` is more like the ternary operator `( expression ? consequent : alternative )` than a C `if`.

**EDIT**

Now that you have added an example usng `return` in C which you want to translate I see that you are not using `return` to return a value but as a `goto` to exit the function early. Since goto [is still considered harmful](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/programming-with-reason-why-is-goto-bad/228200966) just using CL `return-from` isn't always the right answer even if that would certainly be the best literal translation.

In any LISP you need to provide a value to return even though you are not going to use it (for functions called for their side effects). If you are not going to use the value you can just use `nil`:

```
(if (zerop x)
    nil
    (something-else x))
```

If you need more than one statement (for side-effects) you use `let`, `progn` or switch the whole thing to a `cond`:

```
;; using let to bind as well as implicit progn
(if (zerop x)
    nil
    (let ((tmp (gethash x *h*)))
      (setf (gethash x *h*) (+ x 1))
      (something-else tmp)))

;; using progn
(if (zerop x)
    nil
    (progn
      (setf (gethash x *h*) (+ (gethash x *h*) 1))
      (something-else (gethash x *h*))))

;; using cond
(cond ((zerop x) nil)
      (t
       (setf (gethash x *h*) (+ (gethash x *h*) 1))
       (something-else (gethash x *h*))))
```

Comment: I've read somewhere recently that the GOTOs that were considered harmful back when Dijkstra published that article were of the kind that jumps in and out of code blocks freely (making such blocks conceptually have multiple entry and exit points) and in fact at that time even subroutines were considered a novelty *paradigm* when coding in assembly (function call protocols were just a convention to be kept by a programmer). So, it was argued, (and I translate back to our matters) there's nothing wrong with using `return-from` when it is called for, algorithmically. :)

Comment: @WillNess I like the notion of it still be considered harmful and that there are exceptions. That way you think about it every time you write it. It's like `call/cc` in Scheme, which I almost never use.

Comment: I personally like structured localized gotos. YMMV, as *they* say. :)  Just recently I coded some loop in C with two entry points, which sometimes had to perform some internal initialization (following the `concatMap ... span ...` paradigm, basically, working by chunks, yet producing one flat output). Messing with *flags* seems so much *messier*, to me.

Answer (score 1):

You just make the `if` be for the entire body, and put `nil` rather than `return` if you truly want the return to return "nothing".

Thus to add up all the numbers from 0 to n:

```
(defun somefunc (n)
  (if (zerop n)
      0
      (+ n (somefunc (- n 1)))))
```

So if `n==0`, the recursive function returns 0. Else it executes the addition to add `n` to `f(n-1)` and returns that result. (Please note that this is *not* the ideal algorithm, just an example of a recursive function).

Remember, Lisp returns the value of whatever expr was last executed in a function as its value. If `n==0`, the above returns 0. If `n > 0`, it returns the result of the `+` expr.

If you need a multi-step test (for example to make sure you're not being passed a negative number), `cond` is the way (as mentioned earlier). Either way, the value of the last thing executed is the value of the function.